# angularJS in templateUrl can't call function

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm using angular to make page identification  before access to the app main,
in the templateUrl: login.html i cant do anything !

note: when I called the ng-app="myApp"  will give this error : 
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

here my code JS:

```js
angular.module('training')
.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
        templateUrl: 'index.html',
        controller: 'mainCtrl'
    })
    .when('/login',{
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller:  'loginCrtl'
    });
})
.controller('loginCrtl',['$scope','$timeout','apiservice','$routeProvider', function($scope,$timeout,apiservice,$routeProvider){

$scope.ppp= function(){
    alert('ok');
}


}])
.controller('mainCtrl'......
```

here my login.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>

           <script src="public/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script> 
           <script src="public/jquery-ui.js"></script>
     <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
     <!-- <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script> -->
      <script src="controllers/app.js"></script>
         <script src="services/apiService.js"></script>
         <script src="controllers/mainCrtl.js"></script>

</head>
<body  ng-controller="loginCrtl">

<div class="center" style="width: 500px; height: 300px; background-color: #e5e5e5;">
Veuillez authentifier:<br><br>
Login:  <input type="text" id="login"><br><br>
Password:  <input type="text" id="pass">


<br><br>
<button id="ValidAccess" ng-click="ppp()">ok</button>
</div>

</body>

<style >
 .center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 60%;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    padding: 10px;
}
</style>
</html>
```

my index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr"> 
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Planni</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle/bootstrap-tokenfield.css">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle/jquery-ui.css">
            <script src="public/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script> 
            <script src="public/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <script src="public/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
            <script src="node_modules/lodash/lodash.js"></script>
            <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
            <script src="bower_components/moment/min/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
            <script src="public/daypilot/daypilot-all.min.js"></script>
            <script src="public/bootstrap-tokenfield.js"></script>
            <script src="public/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <!-- <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script> -->

                        <script src="controllers/app.js"></script>
                        <script src="services/apiService.js"></script>
                        <script src="controllers/mainCrtl.js"></script>
</head>
<body  data-ng-app="training" data-ng-controller="mainCtrl">
....
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where your ng-app ? module of you is `training` call `ng-app ='training'` not `ng-app='myApp'`
Promblem of you is not setting it use like this

`angular.module('training',['ngRoute'])`

Here is set a module

`angular.module('training',[])`

and here is get a module

`angular.module('training')`

**EDIT**

You use like this

```
angular.module('training',['ngRoute'])
.controller('mainCtrl',mainCtrl) 
.controller('loginCtrl',loginCtrl)

    function mainCtrl(){
    //
    }

    function loginCtrl(){
     //
     }
```

or if you have another module contain loginctr use like this

```
angular.module('anothermodule',[])
    .controller('loginCtrl',loginCtrl)

        function loginCtrl(){
         //
         }
```

And in training app include it

```
angular.module('training',['ngRoute','anothermodule'])
```

Answer (score 2):

first of all, you need to add the ng-app directive to your html file. my recommendation is to add it inside `html` tag

```
<html ng-app="training">
```

then in the js, when you are initializing the module, need to add empty square brackets to the module

```
angular.module('training',[])
```

I assume for the router you are using ngRoute. in that case, you need to inject the route module to your `training` module

```
angular.module('training',['ngRoute'])
```

Comment: I added that ngRoute in training module but when I call this app in html tag I found Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]  !!!!

Comment: did you add the script file in index html for ng route

Comment: yes:   <script src="bower_components/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>

Comment: that is angular.js script you should add angular-route script

Comment: yes I added that you can see the index.html in post

Comment: Could you create plnkr

Comment: the probem is I can't call the same module training in two page html !!